# Is it possible to set the MySQL tables ROW FORMAT with Entity Framework?

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework

I would want the tables to be created in the `Dynamic` row format and not the `compact` one.

Is it possible ?

There is no global option in MySQL 5.6 to set the default row format during table creation.

Answer (score 0):

In 5.6, you can't specify default row format but in 5.7 you can.

Here's the snippet that will do your work in 5.6

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (f1 int unsigned) ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC ENGINE=INNODB;
```

You can read more about this [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-row-format-specification.html).

Comment: Yep, I know, the issue here is the "Entity Framework" part in the question: you don't write your queries :-)

Comment: @VincentdeLagabbe You don't write them BUT there is still a migration file that creates the SQL that does create the table. That SQL could be altered. There is nothing wrong with changing the generated code under certain circumstances.

Comment: Script generation is not implemented in Sapient MySQL driver for entity frameword. So I can't generate a script and then sed it.

Comment: Is there any other driver that supports script generation?

Comment: Nope. Plus I'd rather use the official one. Hence the question :-)

Comment: @webnoob: you can't set this in the migration file unfortunately.